# Enterprise Library issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, enterprise-library

We are using Enterprise Library 6.0  and the following code to create database instance and execute a stored procedure? Any help highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

```
 DatabaseProviderFactory factory = new DatabaseProviderFactory();
             Database  db = factory.CreateDefault();

 DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("ProcedureName");

                OracleParameter outval = new OracleParameter("Test", OracleDbType.RefCursor);
                outval.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                dbCommand.Parameters.Add(outval);

                using (IDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand))
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                    }
                }

<add name="providerConnString" connectionString="Data Source=ABCD;Password=testuser;User ID=testpwd" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
```

Intermittently we are receiving the following exception. This is occurring when we are trying to access the application after an idle time. How the connection pooling happens in enterprise library?How will it work if the application is idle for long time? What is the default min pool size  and default max pool size?

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory' threw an exception.
>   ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.CThreadPool' threw an exception. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class
>   factory for component with CLSID
>   {CB2F6723-AB3A-11D2-9C40-00C04FA30A3E} failed due to the following
>   error: 800703fa Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has
>   been marked for deletion. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800703FA).    at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.CThreadPool..cctor()    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleInit.Initialize()    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---    at System.RuntimeFieldHandle.GetValue(RtFieldInfo field, Object instance, RuntimeType fieldType, RuntimeType declaringType, Boolean&
>   domainInitialized)    at
>   System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.UnsafeGetValue(Object obj)    at
>   System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.InternalGetValue(Object obj,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.GetValue(Object obj)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DataRow providerRow)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSyntheticConfigSettings.GetDefaultMapping(String
>   dbProviderName)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSyntheticConfigSettings.GetDatabaseData(ConnectionStringSettings
>   connectionString, DatabaseSettings databaseSettings)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSyntheticConfigSettings.GetDatabase(String
>   name)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseProviderFactory.DatabaseConfigurationBuilder.b__2(String
>   n)    at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.DatabaseProviderFactory.DatabaseConfigurationBuilder.CreateDefault()

Comment: Enterprise Library does not explicitly do any connection pooling.  Connection pooling would be handled by the underlying provider (in this case I believe ODP.NET).  This [article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40248_01/epm.1112/readme/epm_11123000_readme.html) says to Use Group Policy Editor to change the option for "Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff" to "Enabled".

Answer (score 0):

I had a issue with the App pool identity user in IIS. I removed the identity user and put the default identity user. Then reverted back to my custom user identity. This resolved my issue.